# Does anyone know of a To/Subject control a'la iPhone's Mail and SMS application?

Tags: iphone

I'd like to show a widget with a "To:"-field and a "Subject:"-field, just like Mail application does and the SMS application partly does (it has no subject field). For example, when entering a few letters of a person name a table is shown with relevant hits from the address book. A recipient is encapsulated in a blue bubble. And so on...

Has anyone reversed the MobileMail.app or MobileSMS.app and wrapped it up in an easy to use class? That is my dream ;-)

Thanks in advance!
/John

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out Joe Hewitt [three20](http://github.com/joehewitt/three20/) project, it includes a message composer.

Answer (score 0):

It might be more than you want, because I'm not sure from your question what you're wanting to do with this view.  But there's skpsmtpmessage, an open-source SMTP sender that includes the UI.  It's available at http://code.google.com/p/skpsmtpmessage/

Answer (score 0):

This is a non-answer, but I have looked for this as well, and have not found anything.  I ended up doing something different with my idea that didn't require those fields to be directly input.  I think you'll have to roll your own.

Answer (score 0):

catlan points to a good library there with three20.

Also in 3.0 there is [the new MessageUI Framework](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/prerelease/library/documentation/MessageUI/Reference/MessageUI_Framework_Reference/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008274)

chris.